# How to calculate time difference between two lines in log file?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a log file looking like that:

```
2015-12-03 17:08:36 **START** ACTION
.
...some data
.
2015-12-03 17:08:36 **START** ACTION
2015-12-03 17:08:36 **END** ACTION
2015-12-03 17:08:38 **START** ACTION
.
...another some data
.
2015-12-03 17:08:51 ERROR SEARCHQUEUE-DAILY-SEARCH :: [User1] :: Failed to find item in cache: Black-ish.S02E09.Man.At.Work.720p.EXTENDED.HULU.WEBRip.AAC2.0.H264-NTb[rartv]
2015-12-03 17:08:51 **END** ACTION
2015-12-03 17:08:53 DEBUG SEARCHQUEUE-DAILY-SEARCH :: [User1] :: Unable to parse the filename Christmas.Through.the.Decades.Part1.The.60s.HDTV.x264-W4F[rartv] into a valid show
2015-12-03 17:09:57 INFO  SEARCHQUEUE-DAILY-SEARCH :: [admin] :: Skipping Blindspot.S01E10.nl because we don't want an episode that's Unknown
2015-12-03 17:09:57 DEBUG SEARCHQUEUE-DAILY-SEARCH :: [admin] :: None of the conditions were met, ignoring found episode
2015-12-03 17:09:57 INFO  SEARCHQUEUE-DAILY-SEARCH :: [admin] :: Skipping Arrow.S04E08.720p.FASTSUB.VOSTFR.720p.HDTV.x264-ZT.mkv because we don't want an episode that's 720p HDTV
2015-12-03 17:09:58 DEBUG SEARCHQUEUE-DAILY-SEARCH :: [User1] :: Using cached parse result for: Arrow.S04E08.1080p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H264-RARBG
2015-12-03 17:09:58 **END** ACTION
```

As you can see, there is START action and END action, but between them could be another actions with START and END.
So what i need to do is to check what is the fastest action by finding out the time an action takes by subtracting it's END time from it's START time

I'm new to bash and unix and i have no idea how to do it?

please help!

Comment: This here might be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/539854/calculate-time-difference-between-two-dates

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. What did you try up to now? Can you show us? If you did not try to solve this yourself first, then SO is not exactly the right place. You are supposed to show a minimum of effort. You could maybe take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how to optimize your chances of receiving helpful answers?

Comment: @user12656093 : This is the algorithm: (1) Fetch the time stamps in question, (2) Convert them to a suitable format (for instance _epoch time_) (3) Subtract them (4) Convert the difference into something human-readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk you can use

```
gawk -v min=9999999 '$4!="ACTION" {next}
{t=$1" "$2; gsub(/-|:/, "", t); t=mktime(t)}
$3=="**START**" {start[++c]=t}
$3=="**END**" {t=start[c--]-t; if(t<min) min=t}
END {print "fastest action took " min " second(s)"}' yourFile.log
```

This computes the duration for each action and prints the minimum of all these durations.

If you want to print additional information you can adapt the script accordingly. For every piece of information you need an additional variable similar to `min` that is updated inside `if(t<min)`. To print information about the start line, you also need to store this information in an array similar to `start[]` in the `**START**` rule.

The script takes a general approach, where every action is processed. But this is actually not necessary. If an action contains another action, we know that it cannot be the shortest one, because the action inside has to be shorter. Therefore, we could replace the array with a regular variable and only process the innermost actions.